# Implement lambda layer in lambda function using .net

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

how can I call lambda layers within lambda function  in .net Run time?

Comment: Hi Yuvaraj Yuvi! To allow people help you please add some more detail and be more specific about what you ask.

Comment: I have more than two lambda function . those function i need to call from lambda layer and we need to call in run-time . net environment .

Comment: @YuvarajYuvi Give this a watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EF1NES9BX8c